# My program will run but it prints out all 100's for values that should be all different

Tags: c++, vector, cout

My program will run but when it reaches the point where it prints out some vector values they all come out as 100, as far as my programming skills go (which is pretty low) I see no reason that it should be creating values that are all 100. I think it may have something to do with input_seconds but im not sure.  Any suggestions on whats wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

double altitude(){
    double alti;
    cout << "Please input altitude in meters:";
    cin >> alti;
    return alti;
}

double RoC()
{
    double climbR;
    cout << "Please input climb rate in m/s:";
    cin >> climbR;
    return climbR;
}

double speed(){
    double v;
    cout << "Please input your current speed over ground in m/s" << endl;
    cin >> v;
    return v;
}

//  Gives you the time it will take to reach desired altitude
double time(double A, double R){
    double t;
    t = A / R;
    return t;
}

//Distance travelled horizontally in given time
double distancetravelled(double Veloc, double Time){
    double D;
    D = Veloc*Time;
    return D;
}

//This will convert time to days, hours, minutes, and seconds.
vector<double> converted_time(double input_seconds){
    double days;
    double hours;
    double minutes;
    double seconds;
    days = input_seconds / 60 / 60 / 24;
    hours = (input_seconds / 60 / 60) / 24;
    minutes = (input_seconds / 60) / 60;
    seconds = (input_seconds) / 60;
    //puts values into a vector
    vector<double>times;
    times[0] = days;
    times[1] = hours;
    times[2] = minutes;
    times[3] = seconds;

    return times;
}

void print_vector(vector<double>converted_time){
    cout << "The time it will take for the plane to reach its desired altitude is ";
    cout << converted_time[0] << " days, " << endl;
    cout << converted_time[1] << " hours, ";
    cout << converted_time[2] << " minutes and ";
    cout << converted_time[3] << " seconds" << endl;
}

void print_result (double V, double D){
    cout << "The distance over ground you will travel will be ";
    cout << D << " meters"<<endl;
}

int main(){
    double A;
    double R;
    double T;
    double V;
    double D;
    R = RoC();
    A = altitude();
    T = time(A, R);
    vector<double>converted_time(4);

    double days = converted_time[0];
    double hours = converted_time[1]; 
    double minutes = converted_time[2];
    double seconds = converted_time[3];

    V = speed();
    D = distancetravelled(T,V);

    print_result(V, D);
    print_vector(converted_time);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: didn't check everything but only your initialization for `days` is correct, `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` all got an extra division by 6o that you should remove.

Comment: `hours = (input_seconds / 60 )/60 ;` , `minutes = (input_seconds / 60);` and `seconds = input_seconds;`

Comment: to what do you assign vector<double>converted_time(4) in main ?

Comment: I just want to say that you should probably refactor that code, you got a lot of superfluous lines and also the naming kind of irks me. I can't be the only one that finds it hard to read.

Comment: Also for solving why you get 100 in output please provide what input do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to Change

```
hours = (input_seconds / 60 / 60) / 24;
minutes = (input_seconds / 60) / 60;
seconds = (input_seconds) / 60;
```

To

```
hours = ((int)input_seconds / 60) / 60;
input_seconds -= (int)hours * 60 *60;
minutes = ((int)input_seconds / 60);
input_seconds -= (int)minutes * 60;
seconds = (int)input_seconds;
```

Comment: But wont that display the days, hours, minutes, and seconds as all equivalent to each other? im trying to make it so it will read out like 3600 seconds is 0 days, 60 hours, 0 mins, and 0 seconds. Or where 3800 seconds is 0 days, 1 hour, 3 mins, and 18 seconds.

Comment: @CalElliott check the edit. It should work as you need.

Comment: If i use the value of 10,000 seconds it prints out 2.77778 hours, 0 mins, and 0 seconds. I need it to convert that 0.77778 hours into mins and seconds? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @CalElliott for this you need to typecast all these variable to int.

Comment: I realize this might be annoying for you and I appreciate the help greatly, but I really am a beginner and I have no idea how to do that? could you explain?

Comment: you can change type of `days,hours, minutes, seconds` to int. No need to use `double` type as these value will not be much high.

Answer (score 2):

Issue 1: You are not computing the hours, minutes, and seconds correctly.

```
 days = input_seconds / 60 / 60 / 24;

 // hours = (input_seconds / 60 / 60) / 24;
 // This is wrong since it is same as 
 // hours = input_seconds / 60 / 60 / 24;
 // You need:
 hours = (input_seconds / 60 / 60) % 24;

 // Similarly, change how you compute minutes and seconds.
 minutes = (input_seconds / 60) % 60;
 seconds = (input_seconds) % 60;
```

Issue 2: You are not creating a large enough vector before assigning values to the elements.

```
 // vector<double> times;
 // This creates an empty vector. Use:
 vector<double> times(4);

 times[0] = days;
 times[1] = hours;
 times[2] = minutes;
 times[3] = seconds;
```

Issue 3: You are not calling the function `converted_time` in `main`.

```
vector<double> converted_time(4);
```

just defines `converted_time` to be local variable. You need something like:

```
vector<double> convertedTimes = converted_time(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

This vector never has any space allocated for its members:

```
vector<double> times;
```

And you never really call the `converted_time` function properly either:

```
vector<double> converted_time(4);
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, but how would I properly call the converted_time function?

Comment: Perhaps: `vector<double> foo = converted_time(4);`